# __FRONTEND__ constant not working properly

Tags: php, constants

I have the following directory structure:

```
/webroot
    /static
        /img
        /css
          - style.css
        /js
        /pdf
        /mp3
        /mp4
    - index.php
```

In my `'index.php'` I have the following code:

```
// define the frontend path constant
$frontend = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
define('__FRONTEND__', $frontend);
```

I have my templates in the backend (outside webroot) and when I code something like this:

```
<link type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="<?php echo __FRONTEND__; ?>/static/css/style.css"
/>
```

The CSS code is not shown. I don't get a warning either. When I look in the source I see:

```
<link type="text/css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="C:\xampp\htdocs\projectx\webroot/static/css/style.css"
/>
```

Here you see the different slashes: `'\'` vs `'/'`. Strangely, using the same kind of structure doesn't fail on my backend constant `'__BACKEND__'` which I also have in my `'index.php'`:

```
// define the frontend path constant
$backend = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../backend');
define('__BACKEND__', $backend);
```

Why does my `'__FRONTEND__'` constant fail?

Comment: Did you see the [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) man page? On Windows it'll keep the backslashes, it just removes `../` or ..\ parts. How does your `__BACKEND__` const different from the other one, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` in your templates. It's the system's path, not the one that your users will have access to.

If your web root is *webroot/* as you say, then `href="/static/css/style.css"` will do the trick.

Also, your problem has nothing to do with slashes and backslashes, both work in Windows.

Comment: `'href="/static/css/style.css"'` doesn't work in my case because I have a default template for the `'<head>'`. This creates problems when dealing with different urls: `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/items/audio`. Think I use `'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']'` as my `'__FRONTEND__'` constant

Comment: If your website is hosted on a subfolder (like *example.com/site/*), simply set `__FRONTEND__` to that folder: `define('__FRONTEND__', '/site');`.